# RabbitMQ messages disappearing mysteriously

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I have a node worker waiting for RabbitMQ messages. Today I made some changes to it, and now when I connect the dev instance, everything works—it appears to connect—but then the consume functions don't fire. Messages still disappear though like they've been consumed.

```
Rabbit.queue('consume', function (q) {
    q.bind('consume');

    // This fires
    console.log('Listening to queue...');
    q.subscribe(function (message) {

        // This doesn't fire but message gets removed from queue
        console.log(message);
        init(message);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another process consuming the messages? Have you checked on the management plugin to see what's going on?

Comment: Is it always happening? Or just under heavy load? May be you found the solution since the question? Also would help to know what library do you use, amqp, amqplib, ...

Comment: @old_sound can you see in management plugin which processs is consuming? or how can I easily see that?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same behavior using the RabbitMQ client in a C# console application:

```
  using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
  {
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
      //Various RabbitMQ client magic that doesn't work
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
  Console.ReadLine();
```

Note those last two lines. They keep the console open and running. Otherwise the app would have instantly closed. The problem was I put those two lines of code outside the using statement. Once you step passed the closing bracket of the using statement, the "used" object is disposed. So I was closing my connection and channel almost immediately after opening them. The solution was to put the Console lines INSIDE the using brackets:

```
  using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
  {
    using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
      //Various RabbitMQ client magic that astounds and amazes

      Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
```

Obvious and trivial once you see it, but I wasted an hour on it. I don't know if this is analogous to anything you are doing in NodeJS, but perhaps it will help some other frustrated coder.